# Jade: add two include and mix them

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm creating a web-app to organize events, and i want to show then as a grid and as a list of div. In my code i'm importing two jade file in order to use them as a mixin. This the "main" jade:

```
include blockEventView
include gridEventView

-var events = user.createdEvents

.container#myEvents.hide
  .card
    .lv-header-alt.clearfix.m-b-5
      if(events != null)
        h2.lvh-label.hidden-xs #{events.length} Events
      else
        h2.lvh-label.hidden-xs 0 Events    
    mixin blockEventView(events)
    mixin gridEventView(events,"my-event-grid")
```

blockEventView.jade

```
mixin blockEventView(events)
  .card-body.card-padding
    if events != null
      .row
        each event in events
          .col-sm-4.col-xs-6
            .card.event(data-id = event._id)
              .card-header
                h2 #{event.title}
                  h2.text-rigth 
                    span #{events.length} 
                    if event.participants.length > 1
                      i.zmdi.zmdi-accounts.zmdi-hc-fw
                    else
                      i.zmdi.zmdi-account.zmdi-hc-fw    
                if event.creator 
                  small by #{event.creator}
                else 
                  small by anonimous 
              .card-body.card-padding
                if event.description 
                  p #{event.description}
                else
                  p no description avariable
    else
        h3 No Events
```

gridEventView.jade

```
 mixin gridEventView(events,id)
  .table-responsive
    table(id= #{id}).table.table-striped
      thead
        tr
          th(data-column-id='id', data-identifier="true",data-visible="false")
          th(data-column-id='title', data-identifier="false") title
          th(data-column-id="creator") By
          th(data-column-id="participants") Participants
      tbody
```

And this is the error i get from the server:

```
{ [SyntaxError: /Users/VeaVictis/Project/Organizator/app/views/myEvents.jade:2
    1| include blockEventView
  > 2| include gridEventView
    3|
    4| -var events = user.createdEvents
    5|

Unexpected token ILLEGAL]
  path: '/Users/VeaVictis/Project/Organizator/app/views/myEvents.jade' }
```

So it seems like i can't include two jade file. As soon as i remove the second "include" everything works fine. How can i achieve the feature that i want? So just to be clean i'm looking for a view to include my two files and use them as mixin. Thank you

Comment: gridEventView.jade appears to have an indentation issue at the beginning. is that the case in your original file?

Comment: No it isn't, i edited. Thank you

Comment: try (id="#{id}") instead of (id= #{id}) in gridEventView

Answer (score 0):

Why have you defined the events variable after the includes? Try this see what happens :

```
-var events = user.createdEvents
include blockEventView.jade
include gridEventView.jade
```